# Document height determined incorrectly - can't see all the content

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, height, nivo-slider

I am building a wordpress template, and I use a little Javascript to make the 'content' element fill the page from top to bottom. The goal is to cover the background image, so the 'content' doesn't look cut above the edge on larger screens. The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var h = Math.max($(window).height()+50, $("#content").height());
    $("#content").height(h); 
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    var h = Math.max($(window).height()+50, $("#content").height());
    $("#content").height(h); 
});
```

My layout is: fixed sidebar on the left, then content with auto-width and two floated columns inside. It generally works, however on pages where I have a `nivo-slider` in one of the columns, the document height is determined incorrectly. When the screen size is small, the other column lands underneath (@media statement) and I can't scroll the screen to see that column.

See example page here: http://figtreephotodesign.com/kidsandfamilies/about/ - and set your browser window below 860px-wide to see the problem.
On another page: http://figtreephotodesign.com/kidsandfamilies/contact/ - it works (there is no nivo-slider).

Is it the nivo-slider's css messing up?

Comment: If you stop the Nivo slider on the About page, the images from slideshow are below each other, right? Then your code gets the `height` before Slider is set up, so the slider takes more place. Use your code after initializing Nivo.

Comment: @JakubMichálek I've moved the height javascript to the end of the page, so it loads after the script that runs nivo-slider. It seems to help a little bit - now I can see at least part of the text, but it's still not right...

Comment: I see the Nivo Slider is `onLoad` while your resizer is `onDOMReady`. I still see the problem in this difference, try playing with it more ;)

Comment: I actually never paid attention to these - learning as I go. I put `onLoad` to both, but then the page was loading as short and suddenly jumping to fit 100% height. I then put `onDOMready` to both - it now loads already filled and I see even more of the text, but still not all of it on some window sizes... What is your recommendation?

Comment: My recommendation is to start using `console.log` because any debugging on an already loaded and rendered page form my side is a bit useless, you need to see what the values are when it's executed. ;)

Comment: Ha! Thank you Jakub for teaching me this tool. Now the real fun begins. I see that the 'content' height is determined correctly when the page is reloaded in Firefox and Opera (not in Chrome). Though the values are completely off when the window is resized - in all of those 3 browsers. Chrome for example has some crazy numbers for 'content' height in every way.
Anyway, I wonder how to fix this?

Comment: I can't really say, at this point I usually just log everything possible and spend an hour rearranging until I succeed. :D